# Themekey & Organic Groups

Tags: organic-groups, theme-negotiation

I have a case scenario in which different organic groups can have different themes. Using "Themekey" I allow the user to select a theme when the group node is created and it works fine. When the user is on the group's home page the right theme is selected but when you click on any content (i.e. group content type) that belongs to that group the theme goes back to the default theme. Is there anyway to apply the parent group theme to all content automatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the desired result by using "OG Theme" Module. It adds a field to GROUP pages from which you can select a different theme for each group. Themekey is quite awesome and I will still use it to do mobile version.

Comment: Worth noting that /admin/config/user-interface/themekey/settings/compat allow _other modules_ to take a weight inside the themekey list (priority order). That is, "og theme" can be higher or lower priority than other theming decisions.